# Some questions about LiveCycle Designer

Tags: javascript, xml, pdf, acrobat, livecycle

Good day to all,

I do not really want to ask but I am lost and have no real idea on how to tackle this.

I am just beginning to use LiveCycle Designer and I have no background of any sort about the program.

I would like to ask a few questions.

Can you inject Javascript codes for conditions? (ex. When a check box is ticked, some fields should be disabled)

If you can, where should I put the javascript codes?

I also have the following code:

```
if (this.getField("Allshares").value="off")
{
this.getField("number_of_shares").readonly = true;
this.getField("amountshares").readonly =true;
this.getField("percent_account").readonly = true;
this.resetForm(["number_of_shares", "amountshares", "percent_account"]);
}
else
{
this.getField("number_of_shares").readonly =false;
this.getField("amountshares").readonly = false;
this.getField("percent_account").readonly = false;
}
```

This is the actual script wherein I'm hoping if the checkbox gets ticked, 3 fields should be disabled or readonly.

also, can you suggest some sites that would help me understand live cycle better? I know I might get negatives here but I have been searching for hours and can't find any solution. This is the best shot that I have right now.

Comment: This code will not work, because it is Acrobat JavaScript, which is used in PDF forms. With LiveCycle Designer, you create XFA forms, which have JScript; you'd have to have a serious look at the JavaScript documentation for XFA forms. BTW, are there good reasons why you chose XFA (LiveCycle Designer) for creating the forms?

Comment: It's just a request from a client which is the first time we received that's why we're trying our hands on it.

Comment: OK, if it is the client… good luck with it.